# Django: Maintaining separate sets of objects, almost like 'children'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm currently getting to grips with some of the finer points in Django, and I'm beginning to use it in earnest. I've got an example where I have a few foreign key relationships, and I want to keep the objects separate. Here's a quick `models.py` example:

```
class CopyOfBook(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    copies = models.ManyToManyField(CopyOfBook)

class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Each of those components depends on its parent - for example, a Book can't exist outside of a Library, and is specific to a single library. I know it's a slightly contrived example, but what's the best way to model this in Django?

The problem is, that if you opened up the admin and added a new Book, you'd be presented with a list of all the CopyOfBook instances, rather than just those that belong to that book (which when adding a new one, would be an empty list).

Hopefully I've explained that clearly enough, let me know if you need any clarification.

**Update:** I have been trying to use `ManyToMany.limit_choices_to`, and using the appropriate `related_name` in the arguments, but without much joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by thinking of your entity-relationship model.

A CopyOfBook has a single Book and a single Library. So you can give it a ForeignKey to each.

Book and Library are only connected through a CopyOfBook. So while this isn't strictly necessary (the two above ForeignKey suffice), you can give Library a ManyToMany relationship to Book with through=CopyOfBook.

Answer (score 0):

If a book is specific to a SINGLE library you should rather have a `ForeignKey` to Library on it, than a `ManyToManyField` in `Library`. Also I suppose a `CopyOfBook` will also be specific for a single book, so the same applies here!

You could then administrate the books and copies via [InlineModelAdmins](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)!

Answer (score 0):

The `ManyToMany` relationship that you have between `Library` and `Book` is fine, because more than one library can have the same book.  However, the `ManyToMany` relationship that you have between `Book` and `CopyOfBook` does not make sense to me.  A particular copy can be of a particular book.  What you should have there instead is a `many-to-one (ForeignKey)` relationship, which will associate a particular book with more than one copies of it.